# Is it true that the image of the relative interior is the relative interior of the image?

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a convex subset of a topological vector space. $f$ is a linear function.
Is it true that $ri(f(X))=f(ri(X))$, where ri means relative interior?
If so, is there a reference from which I can quote this result?

Comment: Rockafellar's Convex Analysis, Theorem 6.6 proves this for linear $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: Thanks. But what I want is the more general version described in my question.